# Как добавлять строки в одну колонку sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite3

Столкнулся с проблемой перейдём к сути.

У меня есть таблица:

```
id   code
------------
1    Александр 

2    Павел
```

Мне нужно чтобы по команде, в одну из колонок где айди 1 добавилось еще имя, допустим Дмитрий

```
id   code
----------------------
1    Александр, Дмитрий 
2    Павел
```

Как это сделать? Ведь команда UPDATE попросту заменяет колонку на другое имя

UPD: сразу скажу что concat не работает в sqlite3

Comment: Никогда не храните мульти-значения. Гораздо лучше хранить две записи с одним id и разными code.

Comment: А если мне надо много строк различной информации в одну колонку поместить, просто я не вижу как это красиво можно хранить по другому, если так как вы сказали, то у меня будет неразбериха, а мне нужно хранить допустим Дмитрия только под первым айди

Comment: Вот именно дерьмо и неразбериха будут, если всё валить в одно поле одной записи. нет своего опыта - просто поверь тому, у кого он есть.  Нормальные формы не от нефигом заняться придумали...

Comment: Спасибо, тогда буду делать как вы сказали, вопрос тогда такой а как создавать каждый раз новую колонку, где есть определенный юзер айди который этого требует, с нумерацией, допустим code_1, code_2 ...

Comment: В смысле - колонку? нахрена? у тебя будет для каждого id несколько записей (строк), в каждой из которых - один code. То есть второе состояние таблицы в твоём вопросе будет содержать три записи, две для ID=1, с code=Александр и с code=Дмитрий, и одна с ID=2 и code=Павел.

Comment: А как пополнить эти записи в несколько строк?

Comment: ?? Что такое "пополнить записи"? Запись можно вставить, обновить, удалить и вернуть. Create, Read, Update, Delete - CRUD. Всё.